# ¿Cómo manipulo estos datos entregados para volverlos como una lista separada en Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

El problema que tengo es que cuando se ejecuta la función:

```
answ=fmin(score,(rates),full_output=1,maxiter=1000000)
```

`answ[5]` me devuelve los valores de `A` y `B` juntos en una array y con lista anidada.

Lo que he estado intentado hacer es que me devuelva por separado el valor de `B` y `A` como una lista.

Básicamente así: `[ B, B1, B2, B3....]` y en otra separada `[ A, A1, A2, A3....]`
para poder más adelante llamar a la `listaB` y a la lista por separado y así usarlas.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy import integrate

def eq(par,initial_cond,start_t,end_t,incr):
      t  = np.linspace(start_t, end_t,incr)

      def funct(y,t):
          Si=y[0]
          Zi=y[1]
          Ri=y[2]
          P,d,B,G,A=par

         f0 = P - B*Si*Zi - d*Si
         f1 = B*Si*Zi + G*Ri - A*Si*Zi
         f2 = d*Si + A*Si*Zi - G*Ri
         return [f0, f1, f2]

        ds = integrate.odeint(funct,initial_cond,t)
        return (ds[:,0],ds[:,1],ds[:,2],t)

Td=np.array([0.5,1,1.5,2,2.2,3,3.5,4,4.5,5])#time
Zd=np.array([0,2,2,5,2,10,15,50,250,400])#zombie pop

P = 0       # birth rate
d = 0.0001  # natural death percent (per day)
B = 0.0095  # transmission percent  (per day)
G = 0.0001  # resurect percent (per day)
A = 0.0001  # destroy perecent (per day)
rates=(P,d,B,G,A)


S0 = 500.               # initial population
Z0 = 0                  # initial zombie population
R0 = 0                  # initial death population
y0 = [S0, Z0, R0]      # initial condition vector


start_time=0.0
end_time=5.0
intervals=1000
mt=np.linspace(start_time,end_time,intervals)


findindex=lambda x:np.where(mt>=x)[0][0]
mindex=map(findindex,Td)

def score(parms):
    F0,F1,F2,T=eq(parms,y0,start_time,end_time,intervals)
    Zm=F1[mindex]
    ss=lambda data,model:((data-model)**2).sum()
    return ss(Zd,Zm)

fit_score=score(rates)
answ=fmin(score,(rates),full_output=1,maxiter=1000000)
bestrates=answ[0]
bestscore=answ[1]
P,d,B,G,A=answ[0]
newrates=(P,d,B,G,A)

F0,F1,F2,T=eq(newrates,y0,start_time,end_time,intervals)
Zm=F1[mindex]
Tm=T[mindex]
```

Comment: Si no me confundo, tal y como llamas a la funcion [scipy.optimize.fmin](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html) no vas a poder hacer answ[5] porque el 6º item del array de retorno (`allvecs`) solo es retornado si se usa el parámetro `retall = True`. ¿La llamada en tu código no debería ser `answ=fmin(score,(rates),full_output=True,maxiter=1000000, retall=True)`?  Esto nos genera un array de listas de la forma `[ 0.      0.0001  0.0095  0.0001  0.0001]`. Por favor, aclara esto, además tu código tiene errores de identación y no importas `fmin`

Comment: Primero muchas gracias por comentar y tomarte el tiempo... Efectivamente es tal cual lo dices, anws[5] en este codigo no esta devuelve nada. Para simplificar la pregunta, anws[5] me devuelve en pantalla.  ` [arrray ([0.001, 0.1]), arrray ([0.009, 0.1075]),  arrray ([0.0085, 0.111875]) , arrray ([0.009, 0.1075]), .... ,  arrray ([0.00221837, 0.448458])]`  La pregunta es igual, como e me devuelva por separado el valor de B y A como una lista tanto para A como para B?  Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te he entendido bién quieres que del conjunto de arrays que retorna el sexto parámetro de [`scipy.optimize.fmin()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html) (`allvecs`), extraer el primer elemento de cada array y meterlo en `A` y el segundo elemento de cada array meterlo en `B`.

Como ejemplo vamos a usar una salida ficticia de scipy.optimize.fmin:

```
answ = (np.array([ -0.013,   0.003,]), 213.7582674811338, 228, 392, 0,
        [np.array ([0.001, 0.1]), np.array ([0.009, 0.1075]), np.array ([0.0085, 0.111875]),
         np.array ([0.009, 0.1075]), np.array([0.00221837, 0.448458])])
```

Ante esto tienes varias posibilidades:

- Ya que estas trabajando con `NumPy` puedes hacer el slicing usando su sintaxis, esto te genera dos `numpy.array`:

  ```
  A, B = np.array(answ[5])[:,0], np.array(answ[5])[:,1]
  ```
- Otra opción es usar `zip()` que te retornará dos tuplas:

  ```
  A, B = zip(*answ[5])[0], zip(*answ[5])[1]
  ```
- También puedes usar list comprehensions:

  ```
  A, B = [item[0] for item in answ[5]], [item[1] for item in answ[5]]
  ```
- Y por supuesto un ciclo `for` y `append()`:

  ```
  A, B = list(), list()
  for sublist in answ[5]:
      A.append(sublist[0])
      B.append(sublist[1])
  ```

En cualquier caso todos retornarán un iterable de la forma:

> A = [ 0.001, 0.009, 0.0085, 0.009, 0.00221837]
>   B = [0.1, 0.1075, 0.111875, 0.1075, 0.448458]

Si quieres que todos los ejemplos den listas como salida solo tienes que hacer el casting adecuado a los dos primeros ejemplo (los dos últimos ya retornan listas):

```
A, B = list(np.array(answ[5])[:,0]), list(np.array(answ[5])[:,1])
```

y

```
A, B = list(zip(*answ[5])[0]), list(zip(*answ[5])[1])
```

De todas formas mejor que trabajes con `numpy.array()`

Comment: Eso es exactamente lo que necesitaba. Te agradezco miles... Ahora a buscar a alguien para devolver el favor. Saludos!